# Bash File to move files older than X to S3

Tags: bash, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a bash file to run via a cron job that copies, then deletes locally files/directories older than a certain date to Amazon S3 via their CLI.

I have the S3 CLI installed and working, just don't know how to write the script to copy and delete files.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming older on the basis of modification time

```
find <dir_where_files_reside> -mtime +X | while read line
do
aws s3 cp $line s3://<bucket_name>/
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
rm $line
fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, assuming you have your aws credentials setup.

```html
#!/bin/sh

##############################################################################################################
#
# this script will move any log files that are older than 7 days to s3
#
##############################################################################################################

LOG_DIR=/some/log/dir
DAYS_TO_HOLD=7
NOW=`date +%Y%m%d`

echo "Starting log cleanup process ..."

find ${LOG_DIR} -name "*your_file_pattern_match_here*" -mtime +${DAYS_TO_HOLD} -exec aws s3 mv {} s3://somebucket-that-holds-logs \; >/dev/null 2>&1

echo "Log clean up completed"
```

Comment: Haven't had a chance to play with this yet, but could you also use the same ${LOG_DIR} to create directories in the S3 bucket?
    s3://somebucket/${LOG_DIR}

Comment: You can, the objects are created on the fly under the bucket as long as you have the right aws permissions on the IAM user/role executing those commands.

Answer (score -1):

As discussed on the call please find the scenario-based question, you have to write a script to do the following and share the script :

Scenario - Upload all the files and directories in a drive older than a day to AWS and delete them from the drive